# How to get input.value in JavaScript when the "Enter" key is pressed if I have more buttons next to the input tag?

Tags: javascript, html, button, input

Here I have some code. And I am trying to get the input.value with JavaScript when I press the enter.
If I delete the first button than it is working, but if I leave the code like this, or if I place the first button before the input tag- it is not working.

```js
    const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
    const submit = document.querySelector(".addBtn");
    
    submit.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(todoInput.value);
    })
```

```html
<div class="todo-input-container">
      <form class="input-form">
        <input
         type="text"
         class="todo-input"
         placeholder="Add task..." />
        <button class="btn flagBtn inputFlagBtn">
          <span>
            <i class="far fa-flag"></i>
          </span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn addBtn" type="submit">
          <span>
            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
          </span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Why I can get the todoInput.value when I press the "Enter" key only when I delete the first button from the html?
And what tweak I need to do to make it work with both buttons?

Comment: The form is only submitted automatically when there's only one submit button. When there's more than one submit button, you have to click on one of them explicitly.

Comment: You could put the eventListener on the btn class instead

Comment: I need it work in either cases. So I need it work when I click on the "addButton" class, but I also need it to work when I just hit the enter, too.

Comment: I do have type="submit" only on one button.

Comment: The default type is submit, so the other button is also a submit button. Use `type="button"` to override the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing Enter in the input field only submits the form automatically if there's one submit button.

Your flag button is also a submit button, since that's the default when there no `type` attribute. If it shouldn't be a submit button, add `type="button"` to it.

```js
const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
    const submit = document.querySelector(".addBtn");
    
    submit.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(todoInput.value);
    })
```

```html
<div class="todo-input-container">
      <form class="input-form">
        <input
         type="text"
         class="todo-input"
         placeholder="Add task..." />
        <button class="btn flagBtn inputFlagBtn" type="button">
          <span>
            <i class="far fa-flag"></i>
          </span>
        </button>
        <button class="btn addBtn" type="submit">
          <span>
            <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
          </span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a keydown event listener on your Input field, such that when the user clicks into the input element, types something, then hits enter, the event listener should be triggered.

```js
    const todoInput = document.querySelector(".todo-input");
    const submit = document.querySelector(".addBtn");
    
    submit.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(todoInput.value);
    });


   //jQuery
   $("input").on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) { //13 is keyCode for Enter key
            e.preventDefault(); //look this up
            console.log(todoInput.value);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand jQuery. (monkey covering eyes:)

Comment: Is there a chance to get the help in vanilla JS.

Comment: I just need a solution for both cases. I need to target that value no matter did the user press enter key or click on the "submit" button.

Comment: Should I just go with two different eventListeners? Seems like that might work?

Comment: Sure, you can use two event listeners. You can look up how jQuery works, it much easier than Vanilla. For example: $("input") can be written as document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].